# how to track where my script is running

Tags: php, javascript, dns, google-analytics, tracking

i have a php script that is used by several people, how can i track all the domains that are using or hosting him?

i dont have an ftp to make a call (like if i simulate a image with a php and add the referrer to the track) and also i dont want to bloat the script with a call to another ftp (but google its ok since its well distributed)

right now i have an google analytics tracker on it but he only gets the what goes after the "/" and not the domain

i want a list like:

- www.domain1.com/
- www.another-domain2.org/
- www.freewebhost.com/that-guy-script/

Comment: What if the script thief removes your anti-theft code?

Comment: i know thats a possibility i just want to know how to track not how to protect that code ;D

Comment: OK, what if the user removed your *tracking* code then?

Comment: Don't try for software protection measures. Anything you build in will by bypassed/neutralized/subverted. Go for legal measures instead. "If you copy this software, I get to torture you to death with a wet noodle"

Comment: that's not what im asking, just want to know how to track the domains from where some script have been called / hosted, im not doing it only to protect or something

Comment: Uhm, it's highly likely that you have no right to obtain that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Google Analytics, it *does* track the domain; specifically, as the hostname dimension. You can view it as a secondary dimension in the Content view,
[image: screenshot of the content view with a hostname secondary dimension]

or as part of the Visitor section, under Network Properties.
[image: screenshot of the hostname view]

Answer (score 1):

create a mysql database, with a table that has id, datetime, ipaddress etc.

at the top of your script insert a new record using the $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] global variable.

if database is not an option, log to a file instead.

Comment: i think thats even worse then a call to an php image, because i would need to use a remote mysql connection instead of just a http call

Comment: then log to a file instead as I suggested. You can't track or list anything without making a note of it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing a custom function like this

```
function send_url() {
     $user = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
     $url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/myprocessor.php';
     $ch = curl_init();
          curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // set POST method 
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "site=$user"); // 
          $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
}
```

Simply call the function at the end of the page to send the data you want to process.

Then have another page to process the incoming information, it would be called myprocessor.php in this instance, I will assume you're using mySQL as it's not specified but probably the most common DB to use

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO url_track (url) VALUES($_POST['site'])";
 mysql_query($sql);
```

Please note that this is a very simple code set to get you started and needs some work to actually be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, JavaScript does have the ability to give you an entire domain and I suppose you could just ping an AJAX call with window.location.href, it is likely that this will be detected unless you use some sort of obfuscation, and even then it can be removed.

In PHP, you might be able to get some leverage with `$_SERVER['USER_AGENT']`. If that is set to something other than a browser, you have someone else hosting your stuff. Then you can track their IP through `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']`.